# Nativescript: several quick taps on the button creates multiply load of navigated page

Tags: javascript, promise, nativescript

while creating a login page in Nativescript in vanilla JS I found that if I click multiple times on login button, navigated page loads also several times. This is not expected behavior of course.

See my code here: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=wMZRmJ&v=2

I tried to call onTAP function, as well as a handling a TAP event tapButtonLoginEvent.on(gestures GestureTypes.tap ... as you see in the project. I am also trying to pass (and chain) everything as a Promise,  unfortunately nothing is working correctly. 
To log in: l: "admin", p: "admin"

Here is working example from TJ VanToll https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Hqp5UQ&v=30 that works well, however it is in Angular I am not very familiar with...

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, **of course this is expected behavior.** Your login function is asynchronous that has to hit Kinvey APIs and return the response which can take a few seconds depending on device's internet connection.

Your tap events are synchronous, so as many times you tap, it is going to execute the same login function and upon successful response it's going to navigate to the page as many times you tapped it.

You have to either use a loading dialog to block UI or at least disable the login button while you are still processing the login request. On failure hide the indicator / enable the button back. If it is success then navigate to new page. This is a common behaviour you would follow in any sort of app development.

Comment: Manoj, thanks for your answer. I have already tried to disable login button after first occurrence of a tap event, however it does not work as well. The next page can be still loaded several times. Please see here: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=wMZRmJ&v=3

Comment: login: admin, passw: admin

Comment: I'm pretty sure it must be happening when you come back to login page from home after first login? Because you are adding tap event on page loaded event which will be called everytime when the page is loaded or reload (navigated back form home). So the second time you will have 2 tap events, the 3rd time 3 tap events so it gets loaded multiple times. Either add tap event from XML or do not add tap event the second time by adding some condition to page loaded event.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, it number of loads increases with the each login attempt. It is caused by misplaced tap event, that definitely must not be placed in loaded page event. However, in this configuration, it happens also even app restart - if you clicking on the button really fast.

Comment: However I changed the code according to your suggestion and problem is fixed.  Here it is: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=wMZRmJ&v=4.

Comment: One more question: how is is that in the Angular example such button disable is not necessary?